CSV data is not showing up on my Flutter app screen
I am trying to build a Myntra fashion app in Flutter using a CSV dataset.
This is my code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter_spinkit/flutter_spinkit.dart';
import 'package:csv/csv.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
// ignore: unused_import
import 'product.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<Product> _products = [];
  List<Product> _filteredProducts = [];
  bool _isLoading = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadCsvData();
  }

  Future<void> _loadCsvData() async {
    try {
      final csvString =
          await rootBundle.loadString('assets/myntra_fashion6.csv');
      List<List<dynamic>> csvTable = CsvToListConverter().convert(csvString);

      if (csvTable.isNotEmpty) {
        print('CSV Table Headers: ${csvTable[0]}');
      }

      List<Product> products = [];
      for (var i = 1; i < csvTable.length; i++) {
        print('CSV Row $i: ${csvTable[i]}');
        products.add(Product.fromCsv(csvTable[i]));
      }

      setState(() {
        _products = products;
        _filteredProducts = products;
        _isLoading = false;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error loading CSV data: $e");
    }
  }

  void _filterProducts(String query) {
    List<Product> filtered = _products.where((product) {
      return product.brandName.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase()) ||
          product.description.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase()) ||
          product.category.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase());
    }).toList();

    setState(() {
      _filteredProducts = filtered;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Myntra Fashion'),
        bottom: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: TextField(
              onChanged: (value) {
                _filterProducts(value);
              },
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Search...',
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                  borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                ),
                filled: true,
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                fillColor: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: _isLoading
          ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
          : ListView.builder(
              itemCount: _filteredProducts.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ProductCard(product: _filteredProducts[index]);
              },
            ),
    );
  }
}

class ProductCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final Product product;

  ProductCard({required this.product});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: ListTile(
        leading: Image.network(product.url,
            width: 50, height: 50, fit: BoxFit.cover),
        title: Text(product.brandName),
        subtitle: Text(product.description),
        trailing: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text('₹${product.discountPrice.toStringAsFixed(2)}',
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
            Text('₹${product.originalPrice.toStringAsFixed(2)}',
                style: TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


I tried several debugging steps, but the screen still keeps getting stuck at the circular loading indicator. This is the product model:
class Product {
  final String url;
  final int productId;
  final String brandName;
  final String category;
  final String individualCategory;
  final String categoryByGender;
  final String description;
  final double discountPrice;
  final double originalPrice;
  final int discountOffer;
  final String sizeOption;
  final double ratings;
  final int reviews;
  final String standardizedSize;

  Product({
    required this.url,
    required this.productId,
    required this.brandName,
    required this.category,
    required this.individualCategory,
    required this.categoryByGender,
    required this.description,
    required this.discountPrice,
    required this.originalPrice,
    required this.discountOffer,
    required this.sizeOption,
    required this.ratings,
    required this.reviews,
    required this.standardizedSize,
  });

  factory Product.fromCsv(List<dynamic> csvRow) {
    return Product(
      url: csvRow[0],
      productId: int.parse(csvRow[1]),
      brandName: csvRow[2],
      category: csvRow[3],
      individualCategory: csvRow[4],
      categoryByGender: csvRow[5],
      description: csvRow[6],
      discountPrice: double.parse(csvRow[7]),
      originalPrice: double.parse(csvRow[8]),
      discountOffer: int.parse(csvRow[9]),
      sizeOption: csvRow[10],
      ratings: double.parse(csvRow[11]),
      reviews: int.parse(csvRow[12]),
      standardizedSize: csvRow[13],
    );
  }
}


What should I do in order to correctly display the CSV content in the app?
I tried to debug the code using print statements, and I got this error:
Error loading CSV data: RangeError (index): Index out of range: index should be less than 1: 1


Share a sample of csv data.

From the error message, it may be because you are trying to access an element of the row that doesn't exist in the .fromCsv method in your Product class. Let's take a look (assuming that CsvToListConverter().convert(csvString); doesn't throw any error:

If csvTable is empty or has only one element (what you've called 'headers'), it wouldn't iterate and it would call the setState method, updating your UI with 0 data to display
When having 2 or more items, you are trying to parse an element of the list (starting by index 1 because 0 is already taken) to a class named Product from its data rows. For this, you are trying to parse or take an specific index of the given row, but here is when you possibly get the error.

I would suggest you to add a breakpoint inside the iteration and check if the csvTable[i] you are evaluating at that time has all the values that you need to correctly parse your class.
